# Developing a query to meet a crtierion

Tags: database

I have to develop a query which includes StudentID, FirstName, Last Name, Date of Birth and subject. I'm having difficulties finding all the youngest students for each subject.

I have created a calculating field for Age to show their current age and have used a parameter to return the value of one subject only because I'm not too familiar with how to do the advance parameter to show all which are 'Sports, Sciences, Business and Arts'

Age: Year(Now())-Year([DOB]

When I used the aggregate function below Age it shows all the students. Whereas I only want the youngest for each subject.

Comment: Hi, please edit your question and - show table definition, example table data and expected output, and tag with the proper database platform.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

select StudentID, FirstName, LastName, subject, min(DOB) from students group by subject;